# Razor Pages: Page with partialview inside. How can i store my Data for the partialview?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages, partial-views

Hello guys i am working on a projekt where i can add articles to a cart. My cart is a partialview.When i add a Article to my cart the old data isnt stored and only one (the new article) article is added to my cart.

**This is the code for the Post in my codebehind** Im adding a Postition with RandomNumbers for testing

```
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Position> ArticlePositions { get; set; } = new List<Position>();

    public PartialViewResult OnPostAddPosition(List<Position> articlePositions)
    {
        Random myObject = new Random();
        Random myObject1 = new Random();

        articlePositions.Add(new Position
        {
            ArticleAmount = myObject1.Next(10, 100),
            ArticleId = myObject.Next(10, 100)
        });
        var partialViewResult = new PartialViewResult()
        {
            ViewName = "_ArticlePositonsPartial",
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<List<Position>>(ViewData, articlePositions),
        };

        return partialViewResult;
    }
```

**This is my Partialview with the Model:**

```
@model List<Rechnungen.Models.Position>

<div class="tableFixHead">
    <table class="table table-striped text-center table-sm ">
        <thead class="table-dark ">
            <tr>
                <th style="width:72.5px" class="">Anzahl</th>
                <th style="width:72.5px" class="">ID</th>               
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr id="">
                    <td style="width:72.5px" class="pt-2 ">
                        <span class="TBarticleAmount">@item.ArticleAmount</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:72.5px" class="pt-2 ">
                        <span class="TBarticleType">@item.ArticleId</span>
                    </td>               
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Where i render the Partial:**

```
  <div id="MyPartialView">
   @{
     await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ArticlePositonsPartial", Model.ArticlePositions, ViewData);
    }
 </div>
```

**How i add A Position to cart:**

```
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary"  onclick="GetPartialView()"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>Hinzufügen</button>
```

**And this is my Javascript for it:**

```
  function GetPartialView() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '?handler=AddPosition',
            dataType: "html",
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            success: function(data) {
                 $("#MyPartialView").html(data);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("fail");
            }
        });
    }
```

My code is working so far, when i add something to my cart my site is looking like this=>

[image: Add one article to cart]

When i click a second time on the add button my site looks like this=>

[image: Add a second article to cart]

So my problem is that the Data in ArticlePositions isnt stored. When i Debugg my Code the ArticlePositions are `NULL` when the Post Method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is stateless, so any state created in your `OnPostAddPosition` method is destroyed at the end of the request. You have to implement strategies to persist state across requests. There are a number of options available in Razor Pages. You should research them to identify the most suitable one for your application:

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/state-management

Comment: I know how this shoudl work, but i am not sure how i implement this with an partial view.

Comment: Does my partialview need the same model as my codebehind?

Comment: @flomeu99 No, you can pass any model in to a partial view. If you don't specify a model, the current ViewDataDictionary (Model) will be passed in

Comment: Ok thank your. i tried it and im still stuck at this point. dont know how to solve this problem

Comment: Mangaged so solve it with 'Chache' , thank you for your help.